# Attempting to set up two python flask servers, no port other than 80 will function

Tags: python, flask

I'm doing this as a temporary measure, eventually both servers will be in different locations. For now,  I am trying to host one of the servers on a raspberry pi at 192.168.1.123, port 80, and the other on my computer (temporarily) at 192.168.1.125, port 8080.

I have enabled port forwarding on my router, and allowed the ports in my firewall [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKkJk.png).
I have also contacted my ISP, and they have told me they are not blocking any ports.

This is the code I am using for both, just changing the port=8080 to port=80.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def landing_page():
    return "Hello World"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post your error message as well please!

Comment: I would, but when I went to get the error message the code started working. I'm tearing my hair out now, as I don't know why it's working. I haven't changed anything.

Thanks for your help...